# Inkscape in terminal: convert to greyscale

Tags: inkscape, color-conversion

What is the command for `inkscape` (called from the terminal) to convert graphics to greyscale? I was not able to find in in the manual. I use the following command:

```
inkscape -f drawing1.pdf -A grawing2.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inkscape natively works with svgs. As far as I'm aware, even if you import a pdf it converts it to svg for editing. To avoid the popup window when importing a pdf you have to convert to svg. To do this install [pdftosvg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pdf2svg.1.html) and run

```
pdf2svg inputfile.pdf outputfile.svg
```

To convert to greyscale in Inkscape you have to use Inkscape Verbs. This command worked for me:

```
inkscape -f inputfile.svg --verb EditSelectAll --verb org.inkscape.color.desaturate.noprefs --verb FileSave --verb FileQuit
```

A full list of Verbs can be found by running inkscape --verb-list

Unfortunately Inkscape doesn't have any command-line options aside from basic conversion from svg to png, so Verbs, which results in the window opening, is the only way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this works flawlessly on `svg` files, but gives prompts on `pdf` files, and I have to do dozens of files this way. As well, the windows open which is annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately Inkscape doesn't have any terminal commands besides basic conversion of files between svg and png. Aside from writing a script in Python - which I have no experience of doing - Verbs are the only way to do this. To see a list of command-line options run "man Inkscape".

Comment: Regarding pdfs, Inkscape natively only uses SVG, so to avoid having the window pop up you'll have to convert the pdfs to svgs. I've updated the answer to include instructions on this

Comment: I found that `inkscape` is not a good option, whatever you do, it modifies the dimensions of the images slightly, which is a 100% no-no for me. Thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: Oh no, that's a shame! You should submit a bug report about it

Answer (score 1):

2023 answer:

```
inkscape --batch-process --actions="org.inkscape.color.desaturate.noprefs;export-overwrite;export-do;" myfile.svg
```

Inkscape has changed verbs -> actions. They work a little differently but still a nice feature. To get a list of all actions:

```
inkscape --action-list
```