# Open source PDF to grayscale conversion tool

Tags: pdf, software-recommendation, color-conversion, grayscale

I need a PDF (vector) to grayscale conversion in Linux CLI.

Any open source tool to achieve that task?

I have already tried ghostscript for that task grayscale conversion was happen but fonts are converted to a rectangle box with a cross mark in adobe illustrator. Any solution for that issue?

ghostscript command:

```
- gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -o out.pdf -f in.pdf
```

Comment: Welcome on GS.SE, jaigan, if you are meaning to convert a PDF to a grayscale PDF, see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/inkscape-in-terminal-convert-to-greyscale).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inkscape in terminal: convert to greyscale](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/inkscape-in-terminal-convert-to-greyscale)

Comment: have you tried without the font switch? Are the required fonts available and accessible from the CLI environment when you run this? You might try `-dCCFONTDEBUG` etc to see if there are any clues emitted.